# Scrum workflow software

Tags: project-management, git, communication

I just got hired as a technical director in a new design agency and I would like to set up a proper way to manage projects in the company based on SCRUM techniques.

At the moment we use Bambam which is not very agile, from a technical point of view has not the features Gitlab offers, and it's pretty much useless for the design and account teams.

We are using GitLab to version code and I'm planning on using Flowdock as a communication software.

What I would like is:

- Software for the client to post requests on active projects, feedback
  and comments
- Project management software that follows the SCRUM requirements to
  the letter
- Software for creating tasks/issues (like GitLab) but not just for the
  development team.
- A continuous integration / deployment tool

Everything should be integrated with GitLab and Flowdock (ie. closing issues with commits, synced issues, etc)

If possible, everything should have a nice and easy to use user interface in order to allow clients and employees to pick it up quickly.

Comment: One note.  I have yet to see a "unified" set of scrum requirements or process, whatever you want to call it.  Are you looking at kanban, iterations, hybrid with releases?

Comment: Take a look at Atlassian JIRA and JIRA Agile.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it but you may take a look at [the Axosoft Scrum tools](http://www.axosoft.com/scrum). They have a wide variety of tools to automate and manage individuals and groups also. But I don't know about the GitLab and Flowdock integration though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the founders over at [ScrumDo](http://www.scrumdo.com/) and think we might be a good match for you.

- Software for the client to post requests on active projects, feedback and comments

We have a lot of customers that use ScrumDo with their clients.  Their clients tend to find it intuitive and easy to use.  You can either invite them directly to a team and define their access control, or you can [share a read-only board](http://help.scrumdo.com/help/sharing.html) with them that won't require them to create a login.

- Project management software that follows the SCRUM requirements to the letter

That's a little hard to guarantee since there are several flavor of Scrum depending on who you talk with.  But we do have a very flexible tool and strive to support all Scrum practices.

- Flowdock Integration

I'm a big fan of Flowdock's inbox feature and we have a [Flowdock extra](http://help.scrumdo.com/flowdock/) that supports it.  This lets you post updates to your Flowdock inbox and have those updates grouped by the relevant card they go with.

We don't do GitLab integration *yet*, but it is in the plans to add.

Comment: I love the ScrumDo, its best Agile tool I ever used to manage projects, it is best for both small size team and large teams.

Comment: Any update on the topic of Gitlab integration? I did find this: https://app.scrumdo.com/support/articles/integrations/gitlab-integration